# How to resolve the dependency at compilation time

Tags: c#, .net

I have an application and I have to implement a new functionality (think this area as A) which uses previously existing methods(think it as B). I just need to use B in A.
problem is A is build first and compilation shows it can't find B .
is there any method to trick the compiler.

I'm not allowed to change the build order.

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: Put the interface in the project that A is in. Put the implementation of the interface in the project that B is in. Register the implementation with your IoC container.